# Unable to receive files in request using express-fileupload

Tags: node.js, express, file-upload

I use a REST client to test my app (Insomnia and postman). My app literally does nothing:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
app.use(express.json())
app.use(fileUpload());
app.post('/', fileUpload(), function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.files)
    res.send('a')
});
const PORT =  9999;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}...`);
});
```

Whenever I try to upload a file to this service req.files is undefined. I took this code from express docs page and from a few stackoverflow questions and it just doesn't work for me. `Content-length` is good (40k seems right)[image]

`Content-type` is auto set by my REST client. Do I have to change this?
I tried simply printing whole request object and `body` is empty and `files` is not even present there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for anyone wondering. `fileupload` requires form-data Content-type. Moreover, it also requires a file to have a "key" within this form-data. It's a shame documentation fails to mention this.

Answer (score 0):

Just do one thing: remove file `fileUpload()` from `post` endpoint and check, find below code for your reference.

```
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.files)
    res.send('a')
});
```